# insert triggers not working on sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a electronic  device  called explor which has sqlite database on it where i manually need to enter Verbali table information on it (one by one column)  and  then issue a ticket  at end for the vehicles.I am able to enter all the information on it and when i give a print issue on device  the database just shuts down and I have open it again. the information is not saved on this device from  when i use this trigger.

I have 2 tables  verbalidata and nlist I am trying to insert values into verbalidata and created a trigger for column in verbali data where it should update Nlist column value  for verbalidata column value.
here is my trigger. It just terminates when i try to excute this statament. My insert statment is not created.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Points]
AFTER INSERT
ON [VerbaliData]
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN Targa is not null
BEGIN 
UPDATE VerbaliData
    set VerbaliRuleFourPoints = (select NaughtyList.Points from NaughtyList WHERE
    NaughtyList.VRM = VerbaliData.Targa);

    END
```

Comment: Looks like SQL-Server syntax and not sqlite.

Comment: Can we use update  while inserting a new record

Comment: It doesn't *just* terminate, there is an error message.

Comment: NO CL if it would displayed an error message i would have let you know but it justs shut downs completely. thats my problem. and  can you just tell me if is it possible to update the record  with trigger while inserting the record

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger updates *every* record of the `VerbaliData` table.

You must search for the inserted record, like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Points
AFTER INSERT ON VerbaliData
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.Targa IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    UPDATE VerbaliData
    SET VerbaliRuleFourPoints = (SELECT Points
                                 FROM NaughtyList
                                 WHERE VRM = NEW.Targa)
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid; -- or whatever the primary key is
END;
```

Comment: Thanks CL .. I just have a doubt can an  Insert trigger can 
update  the data that has just been inserted.

Comment: CL i tried your query but still does the same it terminates.

Comment: When will you learn that it is not a good idea to keep the error message a secret?

Comment: ok Cl i have edited my question can you please help me with this.